# php: script updates fields prematurely?

Tags: php, time, strtotime, php4, unix-timestamp

I'm making an auction type website that as you can imagine is supposed to delist products as they expire. the expiration is simply stored as MySQL datatype DATE.

so check_items.php:

```
<?php
function check_items()
{
$con = mysql_connect('localhost','heh','heh');
mysql_select_db('heh_db',$con);
$q = mysql_query("select last_check from ran_last",$con) or die("Check ran_last 1");
$r = mysql_fetch_assoc($q);
//if((time()-strtotime($r['last_check'])) >(60*60*17))//check only once every 17 hours
if(true)
{
    $q2 = mysql_query("select * from Item where expired=0");
    $remove = array(); $count=0;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q2))
    {
        if(strtotime($row['time_expire'])<time())
        {
            echo("strtotime: ".strtotime($row['time_expire'])." time: ".time());
            $remove[$count] = $row['ItemID'];
            $count++;
        }
    }
    mysql_free_result($q2);
    foreach($remove as $next)
    {
        echo($next);
        $q3 = mysql_query(sprintf("select * from Item where ItemID='%s'",$next)) or die("check items outer query foreach");
        $r3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($q3);
        $q4 = mysql_query(sprintf("update Item set expired='1' where ItemID='%s'",$r3['ItemID']));
        if(isset($r3['bidderID']))
        {
            $f1 = mysql_query(
                sprintf("insert into notifications(userID,item_name,ItemID,type,info) values('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')",
                $r3['bidderID'],
                $r3['item_name'],
                $r3['ItemID'],
                "BUY",
                sprintf("You have won the bidding for this item. Contact the <a href=\"pm.php?ID=%s&&expired_item=%s\">seller</a> for details",
                    $r3['userID'],
                    $r3['ItemID'])
                ),$con
            );
            $f2 = mysql_query(
                sprintf("insert into notifications(userID,item_name,ItemID,type,info) values('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')",
                $r3['userID'],
                $r3['item_name'],
                $r3['ItemID'],
                "SELL",
                sprintf("<a href=\"pm.php?ID=%s&&expired_item=%s\">User</a> has won the bidding for your item. You are encouraged to contact each other",$r3['bidderID'],
                    $r3['ItemID'])
                ),$con
            );
        }
        else
        {
            $f1 = mysql_query(
                sprintf("insert into notifications(userID,item_name,ItemID,type,info) values('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')",
                $r3['userID'],
                $r3['item_name'],
                $r3['ItemID'],
                "SELL",
                sprintf("Unfortunately no one bid on your item. You can view expired items from your userpage and re-upload",
                    $r3['userID'])
                ),$con
            );
        }
        mysql_free_result($q3);
    }
    $done = mysql_query("insert into ran_last values()");
}
mysql_free_result($q);
}
?>
```

The script, fully functional, stores the last time it did an update and should only run once every 17 hours. Right now it runs whenever the function is called. Basically whenever I list a product it automatically gets delisted.

Comment: Do not use `mysql_*` in a new code as it is depricated use `PDO` `mysqli_*` instead

Comment: My school promises to update to PHP5 once the semester ends Dec 23.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uh, why are you doing it this way? you can do the filtering in PHP and save yourself a LOT of hassle:

```
SELECT ItemID
FROM Item
WHERE (expired = 0) AND (time_expire < (SELECT last_check FROM last_ran))
```

Plus, you're not even checking for this value when you do the real expiry check:

```
    if(strtotime($row['time_expire'])<time())
                                      ^^^^^^--- shouldn't this be $r['last_check']?
```

Comment: Wow that would be really easy. Honestly I thought sub-queries were illegal. $r['last_check'] stores the last time this script is run. that if statement tells me if the product is ready to be delisted.

Comment: subqueries are legal, but there are limits on them. particularly with `limit` (pun intended). you can't use limit directly in a subquery, but can fake around by putting the limit in a sub-sub-query and just wrapping a `select ** (...)` around it for the intermediate subquery.